# Is the page of Mathworld Wolfram regarding Positive Definite Matrix, wrong?

Tags: linear-algebra

On this [page](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PositiveDefiniteMatrix.html) of Mathworld Wolfram regarding Positive Definite Matrix,
it is stated that

"*A necessary and sufficient condition for a complex matrix $A$ to be positive definite is that the Hermitian part is positive definite.*"

which further implies that:

"*Therefore, a general complex (respectively, real) matrix is positive definite iff its Hermitian (or symmetric) part has all positive eigenvalues*."

---

It is also known that:

[A matrix is positive definite if and only if it is Hermitian and has all positive eigenvalues](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1400002/a-matrix-is-positive-if-and-only-if-it-is-hermitian-and-its-eigenvalues-are-posi) and

[A positive definite matrix must be Hermitian](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/267300/positive-definite-matrix-must-be-hermitian).

However, from Wolfram it seems that a general complex matrix $A$ can be positive definite even if it is not Hermitian (as long as its Hermitian part is positive definite). Are the statements on mathworld wolfram right or wrong?

Comment: Further down on the page you link discusses that Mathworld is not restricting attention to symmetric or Hermitian matrices even though most treatments do.

Comment: The general idea here is that if you have a bi/sesquilinear form $y,x\mapsto x^* A y$, then by some change of basis, you can make $A$ hermitian/symmetric. So that is why, in some contexts, positive definite matrices are taken to be hermitian/symmetric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to its own definition of positive definiteness (a complex square matrix $A$ is called positive definite if $\operatorname{Re}(x^\ast Ax)>0$ for every nonzero complex vector $x$; a real square matrix $A$ is called positive definite if $x^TAx>0$ for every nonzero real vector $x$), the two statements you have mentioned are correct. In the complex case,
\begin{align*}
&\operatorname{Re}(x^\ast Ax)>0\text{ for all }x\in\mathbb C\setminus0\\
&\Leftrightarrow (x^\ast Ax)+(x^\ast Ax)^\ast>0\text{ for all }x\in\mathbb C\setminus0\\
&\Leftrightarrow x^\ast(A+A^\ast)x>0\text{ for all }\in\mathbb C\setminus0\\
&\Leftrightarrow A+A^\ast\text{ is positive definite in conventional sense}\\
&\Leftrightarrow \frac{A+A^\ast}{2}\text{ is positive definite in conventional sense}\\
&\Leftrightarrow \frac{A+A^\ast}{2}\text{ is Hermitian and has a positive spectrum}.\\
\end{align*}
The real case is similar.

However, some assertions on the same page are wrong:

- *“The determinant of a positive definite matrix is always positive”.*
- *“The definition of positive definiteness is equivalent to the requirement that the determinants associated with all upper-left submatrices are positive.”*

These two assertions apply to positive definite matrices in conventional sense only. They are wrong according to MathWorld’s definition. For a simple counterexample, consider the $1\times1$ complex matrix $A=1+i$. If we require $A$ to be real, the first assertion above is true, but sufficiency part in the second one is false — consider $A=\pmatrix{1&-1\\ 1&0}$ for instance.

Comment: If so, it would be great if someone reports the error to Weisstein.

Comment: @colt_browning It would be great if someone convinces the maintainers of MathWorld to stop calling some non-Hermitian matrices positive definite.